# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module 'svelte/compiler'

Tags: svelte

I am trying Svelte 3 but it's throwing an error when running. I have tried two simple configurations mentioned below but they don't work.

1. Module svelte is installed both locally and globally.
2. Module svelte is installed just locally

```
$npm run dev

(node:41186) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module 'svelte/compiler'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/skc/.npm/_npx/41186/lib/node_modules/sapper/dist/core.js:16:30)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    (node:41186) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
    (node:41186) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
    created dist/module.js, dist/index.js in 5.5s
```

Comment: What steps did you take to get to that point? Did you create a project from a template? Which template?

Comment: It was a setup issue. I was working with [svelma](https://github.com/c0bra/svelma) and didn't follow the development guidelines (didn't install npm modules in an internal project). Thanks!

Comment: how did u solve it i have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and fixed it by using Node.js v14.5.0 where's before I was using v.13.2.0.

The warning I got: `(node:22755) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No valid exports main found for '/home/user/dev/coding-tests/svelte/realworld/node_modules/@rollup/pluginutils'`

This happened when running `npm run dev`